# Appending strings across classes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two classes and wish to append a string to a list in Table() from Game()

Here is my code:

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        Table().cards.append("test")
        print(Table().cards)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you will need to initialize the **class Table** inside the **class Game** like this:

```py
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        table = Table()
        table.cards.append("test")
        print(table.cards)

game = Game()
```

Comment: I entered this code into pycharm but it still returns nothing when I attempt to print table.cards

Comment: Can you share your complete code? Probably the problem is somewhere else. Thanks

Comment: I entered this into a completely new test program here is the entire code ```class Table(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        table = Table()
        table.cards.append("test")
        print(table.cards)``` The output is ```C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects1\untitled1\poker2\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user/Desktop/poker2/test_program.py

Process finished with exit code 0```

Comment: sorry the format is kinda scuffed there I'm new to stack

Comment: Did you started the class Game somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Hahahaha don't worry it happens to all of us! :D I am happy that it is working now for you, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that in the print statement you are instantiating a brand new instance of Table, and that new instance is empty.

to correct, include the correct instance of Table in the print statement.

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        table = Table()
        table.cards.append('test')
        print(table.cards)
```